# Why doesn't Beautifulsoup find this input by name?

Tags: python, asp.net, beautifulsoup, python-requests, roblox

I have the following `Python 2.7.10` code with `Requests` and `BeautifulSoup4`:

```
print soup
RequestVerificationToken = soup.find(name="__RequestVerificationToken")
print RequestVerificationToken
```

`print soup` prints the web page I am trying to get information from. In the output, the printed HTML includes the following:

```
<input name="__RequestVerificationToken" type="hidden" value="awbVKuhEwngnc6s6DYPxa0_paAaxyiSus_Gxx2KvZUdQjAAX5bx-icMZyIJJXiVjLniFz8t1YWrrehVZUWj2tGcgA6I1"/>
```

Yet, `RequestVerificationToken` is printed as `None`.

I just want to know if my `soup.find` line is formatted correctly...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

When you pass `name` as an argument - it's interpreted as a *name of the tag* and `BeautifulSoup` would search for a the `__RequestVerificationToken` element instead. Here is how the `find()` method looks (see the first named argument is `name`):

```
def find(self, name=None, attrs={}, recursive=True, text=None,
         **kwargs):
    """Return only the first child of this Tag matching the given
    criteria."""
    r = None
    l = self.find_all(name, attrs, recursive, text, 1, **kwargs)
    if l:
        r = l[0]
    return r
```

Instead, check your `name` attribute inside `attrs`:

```
soup.find(attrs={"name": "__RequestVerificationToken"})
```

Comment: Thanks! I also needed to get its value, but adding `['value']` after the line you provided worked.